# How do i change the column time format in fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

Am trying to change time format into 24H watch in full-calendar.

I tried to find it [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) but am unable to figure it out.

[image]

Here the code snippet:

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: false,
    weekends: true,
    timeFormat: 'H:mmtt{-H:mmtt }',
```

Please have look to **snap** and help me. Thanks...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `axisFormat: 'HH:mm'` to accomplish this. Let me know if this helps.

---

Just to complement: in version 2.4.0 this method was renamed to [slotLabelFormat](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotLabelFormat/).

Answer (score 13):

I use FullCalender V4.2.0 this work for me:

```
        slotLabelFormat: [
        {
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            hour12:false
        }
        ],
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me

Comment: Fullcalendar v.5 this works aswell.